# Do JSONP requests with jQuery bypass Varnish?

Tags: jquery, jsonp, varnish

I am working with a third-party webservice that has Varnish in front of it.  Varnish is there because it is read-only, and uncached requests are rather slow.

I am querying the webserivce using jQuery and JSONP.  Normally, [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) employs cachebusting via an extra GET parameter with JSONP (per the docs for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).  Since my webservice is read-only, I would like cached results, so I am making my calls like

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://example.com/json/callback=?",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  cache: true,
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

I can watch the requests go out with the network tab in Chrome, and they look like

`http://example.com/json?callback=jQuery171047077397373504937_1348163237407&arg1=foo&arg2=bar`

Since `cache=true`, I am not getting the extra "`&_=[TIMESTAMP]`" in the request.

Responses are very, very slow to come back, so I think that I am effectively bypassing the Varnish because of the `callback=` portion of the request.

In other words, is it accurate to assume that Varnish is considering each request different because jQuery uses a unique callback key for every call, and therefore I am never getting back cached results?

I would like to make sure I have identified the right problem before I ask the third-party to alter their Varnish, ala [Ignoring GET parameters in Varnish VCL](https://serverfault.com/questions/112531/ignoring-get-parameters-in-varnish-vcl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only your callback string is not a get variable but just a part of the request URL. For making it simple in your varnish configuration you can add a ? to that URL to make it
http://example.com/json/?callback=jQuery171047077397373504937_1348163237407&arg1=foo&arg2=bar

Alternatively you can use regsub() on req.url in your varnish config with something like;

```
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "callback=jQuery\d+_\d+&", "");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I fat fingered the URL when I sanitized it; it does have the ? in it.  Do you agree that the callback= is causing the request to never be cached by Varnish?

Comment: It looks like it will change on every request, yes? I only use named callbacks so not sure how the callback generation works. If it's indeed unique with every request, then you could also solve it by changing it with jsonpCallback property on your call.

Comment: I have no idea how may times I have read that doc page, but I never noticed the "jsonp" and "jsonpCallback" options for $.ajax().  That does look like it is fixing my problem.  Thanks.